# Taking double limit inside the integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am familiar with the convergence theorems like DCT, MCT and BCT which allow us to interchange limit and integral. However I wonder whether the same can be used to interchange Integral with a double limit. If such a thing happens, it will be very useful. For example, when is the below equation true?
$$\lim_{m,n \to \infty}\int_{X}(f_n+f_m)g=\int_{X} \lim_{m,n \to \infty} (f_n+f_m)g.$$
Any references will be helpful.